# Set __name__ to '__main__' on module before execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have code that checks `if __name__ == '__main__'`  and then calls some function if that is the case. Currently, I execute this code by spawning another python subprocess, but importing it as a module is cleaner. The problem is that there is no `main` function in these modules is exactly what is executed under `__name__ == '__main__'` varies. The only option that I really have is to set the `__name__` attribute before executing the module. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: why do you add `if __name__ == '__main__'` when you want it to be executed on import?

Comment: It's not my code.

Comment: If you can't just make a `main` function, I recommend *not* importing this file. Just carry on running it the way you've been running it. Among other things, what happens if you need to run the code twice? You can't just re-import it. There are a lot of complications with trying to get this code to work as a module if you can't change the code.

Comment: That sounds like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/317868). Could you clarify why you want to execute all of these branches and what the purpose of that code is?

Comment: make the code in `if __name__ == '__main__'` a method!

Comment: The whole point of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` check is so that it will only run the script if you use it as a main program, and **not** run it when you're loading it as a module. When you use it as a module, the main script should be in the calling program.

Comment: @MSeifert What I actually want to do is receive a full traceback on a KeyboardInterrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [runpy](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/runpy.html) library.

```
runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name= "__main__")
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is the following:

```py
imp_new_module = type(sys)
new_module = imp_new_module(module_name)
new_module.__dict__['__name__'] = '__main__'
exec(open(scriptname).read(), new_module.__dict__)
```

This is similar to what the importlib internals do, but does skip some attributes.