# How to monkeypatch '__name__' with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a file 'mymodule.py' that I want to test with 100% coverage using pytest. This is the content of the file:

```
def important_function():
    print('I can test this function easily.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('I want to test this part.')
    assert False
```

I want to test the code under `if __name__ == '__main__':`
Since I added `assert False` this test is expected to fail.

I am using the `pytest` framework and I do not want to use `unittest` or anything from its family, like `unittest.mock`.

In my last unsuccessful attempt I was trying to monkeypatch `__name__` from `builtins`. This is the content of test file:

```
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch
monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()
import builtins
monkeypatch.setattr(builtins, '__name__', '__main__')
import mymodule
```

It did not work, because it did not fail.

Comment: `__name__` is not a built-in.

Comment: How about `def main(): assert False` then `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`?

Comment: ^ This will not produce a test with 100% coverage. It will definitely allow to test test the code inside `main()` but my purpose is to test the line just below  `if __name__ == '__main__':`.  Thank you

Comment: Have you seen the possible suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683906/set-name-to-main-on-module-before-execution ? importlib might also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. That question solved the issue: `runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name= "__main__")`